# How to get radio button group functionality for each row in a table using jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces

How to get layout like the following using `h:selectOneRadio` encapsulated within a `rich:dataTable`

```
row1   col1   col2   col3

row2   radio1 radio1 radio1

row3   radio2 radio2 radio2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are three ways of doing that:

1. Use the Tomahawk `<t:selectOneRadio>` and `<t:radio>` components, as described by [Bozho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho). This is the simplest solution. The only drawback is that you have to integrate another components library in your project (`Tomahawk`). However, this library is compatible with others libraries, like [Richfaces](http://jboss.org/richfaces) or [Icefaces](http://www.icefaces.org/main/home/).
2. Create your own component for that. This is more complex than the previous solution, and may not be really interesting as the `Tomahawk` library is already providing this component...
3. Use the "basic" `<h:selectOneRadio/>` component and then use `Javascript` code to move the radio elements where you want. In my project, I had a popup that contains a list of checkboxes, but I wanted to display all of them in two columns. Unfortunately, the `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` component only provides the `pageDirection` and `lineDirection` layouts. So I decided to display them using the `pageDirection` layout, and then manipulate the generated HTML code to break the list into two parts, using Javascript.

So here is what I did on the JSF code:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="rolesSelection" value="#{myRolesBean.selectedRoles}" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myRolesBean.RolesList}"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    splitElementsIntoTwoColumns("myForm\\:rolesSelection");
</script>
```

and the Javascript function (using `jQuery`, which is bundled in `Richfaces` library):

```
function splitElementsIntoTwoColumns(tableId) {
    var idx = 1;
    var row, next;
    while ((row = jQuery('#' + tableId + ' tr:nth-child(' + idx++ + ')')).length) {
        if ((next = jQuery('#' + tableId + ' tr:nth-child(' + idx + ')')).length) {
            row.append(next.find('td'));
            next.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

(more explanations about this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261998/modifying-the-structure-of-a-html-table-with-jquery))

In your case, the Javascript function will be harder to write, as you want to move the radio buttons within a table generated by a `<rich:datatable>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Tomahawk's [`<t:selectOneRadio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_selectOneRadio.html) with `layout="spread"` and place one `<t:radio>` in each `<rich:column>`